# PHP - Selecting database from MySQL doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have read a lot about this but it still doesn't work.
I'm just trying to select a database to create a new table in, I try:

```
$db = mysqli_select_db("test");
if(!$db) {
echo "error: " . mysqli_error($db);
}
```

But I still get an error (and mysqli_error($db) doesn't seem to work).

Of course I have already connected to it:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "administrator", "****");
```

On phpMyAdmin I have these databases:

[image]

Why can't I select "test" ?
And creating a database doesn't work because I don't have the rights, as you can see.

Comment: Are you using mysqli_connect first?

Comment: have you actually connected to the database before this line with mysqli_connect or new mysqli?

Comment: Yes, I think I should've added that code too

Comment: do you have the rights to access the database? what's the error message?

Comment: on your connection ur missing the conection host user and pass check the documentation

Comment: Does the connection attempt from `mysqli_connect()` succeed? (If you're  not sure check the value of `$con`.)

Comment: you can select the database by writing its name in the `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: You should use `mysqli_error($con)` to get the error message. It needs a connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedular signature of this function is:

```
 bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

So you will have to provide the resource you got back from the `mysqli_connect()` to make it work. Something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "administrator", "****");
$success = mysqli_select_db($con, "test");
```

Alternatively you could specify the database on the connect call with a 4th argument:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "administrator", "***", "test");
```

See the [examples on mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).

Comment: Wow...this was actually it.
Thank you, and sorry if the question was too obvious, I read so much about this and didn't find this...

Comment: Btw, you could select the db with the [`mysqli_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) too.

Comment: @Big_Chair Just read the documentation linked to: it's the fourth parameter.

Comment: Added to the answer anyway (-:

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_select_db` function requires two parameters `link` and `dbname`.  Please refer to the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

You are only passing `link` and no database name in your call:

```
$db = mysqli_select_db("test");
```

Comment: @Big_Chair, yes, noticed that, I guess I was typing the answer when complex857 submitted the answer.  I don't want to delete this post for the documentation link :)